# Difference in the Four Color Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

How is proving that any planar graph with maximum degree of four has a four coloring, different from proving the four color theorem? If they are different, then how would one prove it?

Comment: ummmm.... they're different because there are planar graphs with maximum degree exceeding 4.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas So is my statement much easier to prove than the four coloring theorem?

Comment: Yes it is a LOT easier, for instance using Brook's Theorem.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem